# python logger logging same entry numerous times

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-logging

I have a such logger initializing function:

```
def generate_logger():
    import logging
    LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "mylog.log")
    FORMAT = "%(asctime)s : %(message)s"
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```

And at some part of my code I have such exception catching:

```
logger = generate_logger()
except AttributeError:
    logger.error('Opps we got an error')
```

Weirdly I get same error written 2 times and it can be caugh only once, once I change `logger.error('Opps we got an error')` with `print "test"`, I get "test" printed once.

What can be the problem and the solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are adding a new FileHandler to the root logger every time you call that function: the call to `logger.getLogger()` without a name argument returns the same logger object every time.

You should call `generate_logger()` only once and then simply get the same logger object by calling `logger.getLogger()`:

```
generate_logger()

# .... some time later

log = logger.getLogger()
except AttributeError:
   log.error('Opps we got an error')
```

(note that you do not need `generate_logger()` to return a value now)

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same problem and came across this page. Yes, I was also creating multiple handlers. In `generate_logger()`, you can check if there's any other handlers and delete them.

```
def generate_logger():
    import logging
    LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "mylog.log")
    FORMAT = "%(asctime)s : %(message)s"
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # Reset the logger.handlers if it already exists.
    if logger.handlers:
        logger.handlers = []
    fh = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're probably getting two handlers added to the logger somehow. Perhaps at some point an implicit handler is being added.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have two handlers going to the same resulting log.

How many handlers are you creating?  How many times are you executing `generate_logger`?  Each time you execute `generate_logger` you'll create another handler to the same file, leading to potential duplication.

Answer (score 0):

use can use singleton design pattern for this:

43 class Singleton(type):
 44     """
 45     Define an Instance operation that lets clients access its unique
 46     instance.
 47     """
 48
 49     def **init**(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
 50         super().**init**(name, bases, attrs)
 51         cls._instance = None
 52
 53     def **call**(cls, *args, **kwargs):
 54         if cls._instance is None:
 55             cls._instance = super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)
 56         return cls._instance
 57
 58
 59
 60 def _setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
 61     """Function setup as many loggers as you want"""
 62
 63     handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
 64     handler.setFormatter(formatter)
 65     logger = logging.getLogger(name)
 66     logger.setLevel(level)
 67     logger.addHandler(handler)
 68
 69     return logger
 70
 71 class Logger(metaclass=Singleton):
 72
 73     def **init**(self, file_name, level):
 74         if not (isinstance(file_name, str) and
 75                 isinstance(level, int)):
 76             raise ValueError("Invalid Args")
 77
 78         self.log_inf = _setup_logger('inf', file_name+'.inf', level)
 79         self.log_err = _setup_logger('err', file_name+'.err', level)